# Parsing an array to String Tokeniser

Tags: java

I have an object declared in this format

```
StringTokenizer star = new StringTokenizer(st , SEPARATOR);  //separator is '/'

Session s1 = new Session(int SessionID, String [] cineName, String[] cineType, String movieName, String date, int time);

int SessionID  = Integer.parseInt(star.nextToken().trim()); //for integer
String movieName = star.nextToken().trim(); //for string
String [] cineName = ? //how about string array?
```

Thus, I wish to ask how I can implement the parsing of a cineName array.

Comment: What is the input, what is the expected output? We can't read inside your brain, and we can't see your screen. Do you know how to loop in Java? If not, then learn that first.

Comment: How the string array separate items?

Comment: **Please give us an example of input.** I think you need to do a loop in order to read the values from `star` and put them in the array cineName.

Comment: Also, don't use `StringTokenizer`, just use the `split` method provided on `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the tokens of a String which delimits tokens with "/" in cineArray as follows:

```
int tokens = star.countTokens();

for (int i=0;i<tokens;i++)
{
     cineName[i] = star.nextToken().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] cineName = star.nextToken().trim().split(CINE_NAME_ARRAY_SEPARATOR);
```